# Can you use power as a probability to calculate expected outcome in A/B tests?

Tags: statistical-power, ab-test

**Background:**

I'm trying to think about a cost/benefit framework for decision making based on results from an A/B test, 
my question is specifically about the use of power as a probability in a simplified expected outcome equation

**Question Setup**

Say we ran an experiment like so:

- Null Hypothesis: no change in conversion rate
- Alternative Hypothesis: variant conversion rate > control conversion rate
- Observed conversion rate increase:  +0.035%, stat sig 95%
- Power, with a minimum detectable effect size of +0.04% was 65%.

Now, we calculate that a +0.04% in conversion rate translates to 1,000,000 in gain. The cost to run the experiment was 100,000 in resources

My understanding is that power is the probability of rejecting the null given that it is false. So 65% of the time you would observe a lift of at least 0.04% and in that outcome, a net gain of 900,000 and 
35% of the time you would falsely reject the null (which was no improvement) and see the outcome of net loss of -100,000

Therefore, is it valid to use power as probability in following expected benefit equation?

0.65*(1,000,000 - 100,000) + 0.35*(0 - 100,000) = 550,000

Comment: Could you explain how you got from "at least 0.04%" to an equation that uses *exactly* 1,000,000 for the gain?  Doesn't "at least 0.04%" include situations where there's a much greater gain?  What happened to those?  And what happened to the situations with positive but smaller increases in conversion rate where your test correctly concludes there is a real increase?

Comment: @whuber you are right, this is way more involved than I initially thought. I see the "at least .04% = 1,000,000 gain" is only one number in the infinite number of gains above .04. You'd almost need to integrate or something over [0.04, infinity). And this happens along the entire power curve of effect sizes doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps this would involve the integral of (power * gain $) for all lifts ranging from 0 to infinity ? There might be something about the negative lifts as well and the corresponding negative gains...